# Bash: How to invoke command and store the result in a variable?

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

Basically I want to be able to invoke a given command, in this case `mysql -uanon -ppwd -db mydb -e "select count(*) from table1"`. And then take this commands result (the count on that table) and place it in a variable in bash script. What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You most likely want to use batch mode (-B) and disable column names (--disable-column-names)  for non-interactive mysql output:

```
out=$(mysql -B -db mydb -uanon -ppwd --disable-column-names  -e "select count(*) from table1";)
```

Comment: For Linux newbies, make sure there are no spaces between variable name, the = sign and the expression that follows. Bad things can happen.

Answer (score 14):

```
$ A=$(mysql -uanon -ppwd -db mydb -e "select count(*) from table1")
$ echo $A
```

In other words, use the $() syntax.