# How to quote / symbol inside $()

Tags: bash

Suppose, I have this simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

text="3.14159"
echo "$text / 10" | bc -l
```

prints:

```
.31415900000000000000
```

Which is correct. Then I wanted to put the output into a variable, using $() syntax from here: [Bash: How to invoke command and store the result in a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730766/bash-how-to-invoke-command-and-store-the-result-in-a-variable)

```
#!/bin/bash

text="3.14159"
out=$("$text / 10" | bc -l)
echo $out
```

And got an error:

```
test.sh: line 4: 3.14159 / 10: No such file or directory
```

It treats division symbol as a directory separator.

How to fix?

Comment: `out=$(echo "$text / 10" | bc -l)` or better `out=$(bc -l <<< "$text/10")`

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf - I didn't see your comment when I started trying this out on my shell. If you are game to capturing your solution in an answer, I'll remove mine.

Comment: @Chandranshu don't worry, I'm fine with just this comment `:)`.

Comment: +1 for here string, so few people use this wonderful redirect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change line 4 to be:

```
out=$(echo "${text} / 10" | bc -l)
```

Answer (score 2):

What the construct `$(xyzzy)` (for any `xyzzy`) tries to do is to execute that command and provide its standard output on the command line of the invoking command.

Since `"$text / 10"` is not a valid command, that's why you're running into problems. You should provide the *entire* command (i.e., including the `echo` bit) from your first sample inside the parentheses:

```
pax> text=3.14159 ; out=$(echo "$text / 10" | bc -l) ; echo $out
.31415900000000000000
```

There's also other ways to do this. You can use a here-string solution, such as:

```
pax> text=3.14159 ; out=$(bc -l <<<"$text / 10") ; echo $out
.31415900000000000000
```

What this does is similar to `bash` here-docs except it's a little more limited. It expands the word given after `<<<` and provides that (with a trailing newline) as standard input to the command.

And, of course, `bc` is not the only command you can use. If, like me, you've had your mind warped bu doing too much Forth programming, the RPN `dc` calculator can also come in handy:

```
pax> text=3.14159 ; out=$(dc <<<"50 k $text 10 / n") ; echo $out | sed 's/0*$//'
.314159
```

In this, example, `50 k` sets the precision, `$text 10 /` works out the formula and `n` pops off the value and prints it. The `sed` trick is simply to remove trailing zeroes from the output.